# Alternative self hosted solution for google apps (mainly document/spreadsheet)?

Tags: google-apps

As titled, I'm finding for a software can be installed on my own server, to replace for google apps.
I'm open to commercial solution, the point is I want to keep the data on my own server.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: It would help if you could detail your requirements. Do you want document/spreadsheet editing via a browser? Or offline editing (using Office or OpenOffice) but online storage? Multi-user editing?

Comment: Multiple users can edit online via browser is my most prefer. Offline editing but online storage is also ok if no choice, surely multi-user editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okie doke. This is actually pretty challenging -- you're asking for online editing, which is very cloud-oriented, but using a private server. If all you wanted was file services, then you'd have a lot of options -- OwnCloud.org is a personal favorite, but there are a bunch.

If you really want to be able to edit online but save to a private server, SharePoint comes to mind first. Alfresco and its ilk are also out there, but that's enterprise-oriented. There are theoretically some ways to use OpenOffice programs in a browser (see also [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077861/open-source-tools/web-based-spreadsheets-with-openoffice-org-and-dojo.html)) but I've never seen them in action.

Hope that gets you started. Good luck.

Comment: You really provide me much valuable advice. Thanks a lot

Comment: I would recommend Owncloud (self-hosted file storage) and Onlyoffice (self-hosted office suite), and if you can get them working together, even better! It is possible to integrate the two, so that you can edit a document in owncloud, using Onlyoffice. Integrating Owncloud and Onlyoffice: http://www.onlyoffice.com/blog/2017/02/integrate-onlyoffice-online-editors-with-owncloud/